# ¿por que me da NaN?

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de realizar una funcion cuadratica y me devuelve NaN
¿Me ayudan Por favor?

```
var a= parseInt(prompt());
var b= parseInt(prompt());
var c= parseInt(prompt());
var d=Math.sqrt(b-4*a*c);
var e=d-b;
e=e/(2*a);
document.write("<p>"+e+"</p>");
var f = d*-1;
e=f-b;
e=e/(2*a);
document.write("<p>"+e+"</p>");
```

Comment: haz un console log a odas tus variables y ve si todas traen valores

Comment: a partir de "d" me muestra NaN

Comment: Incluye en tu pregunta los valores que usastes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta bien, el problema que tienes es los números que estas ingresando.

```
var d=Math.sqrt(b-4*a*c);
```

Calcula la raiz cuadrada, pero recuerda que si **`b-4*a*c`** es **negativo**, entonces **es indeterminado.**

debes validar que **`b > (4*a*c)`** o que **`b-4*a*c >= 0`**

para que veas lo que digo, prueba cone estos valores.

```js
var a= parseInt(1);
var b= parseInt(20);
var c= parseInt(2);
var total_raiz = b-4*a*c;
if(total_raiz < 0){
 console.log("No es posible encontrar la raíz cuadrada de un número negativo");
}else{
 var d=Math.sqrt(total_raiz);
 var e=d-b;
 e=e/(2*a);
 document.write("<p>"+e+"</p>");
 var f = d*-1;
 e=f-b;
 e=e/(2*a);
 document.write("<p>"+e+"</p>");
}
```

Comment: Hola Alfredo, no creo que sea indeterminado, mas bien no existe en los reales, pero puedes obtener raíces negativas en los números complejos.

Comment: en realidad se conocen como [numero imaginario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_imaginario)

Comment: si @KevinSuaza tienes razón.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes sacarle la raiz cuadrada a un numero negativo, la variable b debe ser mayor que 4*a*c entonces valida en el código antes de realizar la operación

```js
 var a= parseInt(prompt());
var b= parseInt(prompt());
var c= parseInt(prompt());
if(b < (4*a*c)){
 document.write("No se pueden obtener raices reales");
}else{

  var d=Math.sqrt(b-4*a*c);
  var e=d-b;
  e=e/(2*a);
  document.write("<p>"+e+"</p>");
  var f = d*-1;
  e=f-b;
  e=e/(2*a);
  document.write("<p>"+e+"</p>");

}
```